# Not seeing Previous Version menu choice in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

As above. The Previous Version of a Dropbox folder (or file) does not show up as a menu choice on the main dropbox.com site.

Not sure how to make that appear.  thanks, :-)

[image]

Comment: What is the question here?  If you just have an issue with the Dropbox website, contact Dropbox support.

Comment: There are over 3,000 DB tagged questions on SO. Here I may get an answer in minutes. With DB, it could be a few hours. Speed is of the essence.  :-)

Comment: but you didn't ask an actual question.. you just made a few vague statements.